# How to save array from one sub to pass it into another?

Tags: excel, vba

Example:

Sub1 generates an array
Sub2 Uses that array

The only time it works is by calling Sub2(array as Variant) inside Sub1(). I declare the array variable globally.

```
Dim arr1() As Variant
Sub aaa()


Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer

startingPoint = "B2"


col = Range(startingPoint).Column
row = Range(startingPoint).row

cols = Range(Cells(row, col), Cells(row, col).End(xlToRight)).Count
ReDim arr1(cols)

For myCounter = 1 To cols
    arr1(myCounter) = Cells(row, col + myCounter - 1).Value
Next

For myCounter = 1 To cols
    Cells(myCounter, 1).Value = arr1(myCounter)
Next

bbb (arr1)


End Sub

Sub bbb(arr1 As Variant)
Dim myCounter As Integer
For myCounter = 1 To 4
    Cells(myCounter, 1).Value = arr1(myCounter)
Next
End Sub
```

If i dont call sub bbb inside sub aaa, it doesnt even let me to execute sub bbb. The only way it works is the code above, but i dont want to call sub aaa everytime i need to call sub bbb, i want to save the array generated by sub aaa and use it in other subs without calling it again. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it possible to call the second `Sub` independently, don't use an argument. So change these two lines of code:

1. In `aaa`:

   ```
   bbb ' Call without argument
   ```
2. The definition of `bbb`

   ```
   Sub bbb() ' No arguments
   ```

Comment: The extraneous parentheses in the procedure call, are [potentially dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153905/1188513), given how VBA interprets them. Don't put parentheses in VBA procedure/member calls, unless your calling a function or property getter that's taking arguments. Or, use the deprecated `Call` keyword.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, parentheses removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend to have aaa return the array instead of using a public variable.

```
Function aaa()




Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer

startingPoint = "B2"


col = Range(startingPoint).Column
row = Range(startingPoint).row

cols = Range(Cells(row, col), Cells(row, col).End(xlToRight)).Count
Dim arr1(cols) as Variant

For myCounter = 1 To cols
    arr1(myCounter) = Cells(row, col + myCounter - 1).Value
Next

For myCounter = 1 To cols
    Cells(myCounter, 1).Value = arr1(myCounter)
Next

aaa = arr1

End Function

Sub bbb()
   Dim arr1() as Variant 
   arr1 = aaa()

Dim myCounter As Integer
For myCounter = 1 To 4
    Cells(myCounter, 1).Value = arr1(myCounter)
Next
End Sub
```