# Converting VBA Collection to Array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an array with all the worksheet names in my workbook that have the word 'Template' in it. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to create a collection first and then convert it to an array but I am having trouble. Right now the error I am getting is on the

```
collectionToArray (col)
```

line. I am receiving an

> Argument Not Optional error

Pretty stuck, any help is super appreciated. Thanks!!

```
Public col As New Collection
Public Sub Test()
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "Template") <> 0 Then
        col.Add ws.Name
    End If
Next ws

collectionToArray (col)
End Sub

Function collectionToArray(c As Collection) As Variant()
    Dim a() As Variant: ReDim a(0 To c.Count - 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        a(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next
    collectionToArray = a
End Function
```

Comment: Try removing the brackets. I'm not sure why you need to do both, why not just a collection or just an array?

Comment: Valid point... is there a collection equivalent for IsInArray? @SJR

Comment: What I mean is that at the end of Test you have a collection of the sheets of interest so you can then work on that. Why do you need anything else?

Comment: @SJR Right, you're right. Is there a way to test if a string is in my collection easily? I only knew how to test if something is in an array.

Comment: OK now I see what you are asking I think. In fact use a Dictionary instead, which has an Exists method (or just stick with an array).

Comment: @SJR Ah yeah I could do that, let me try some stuff and i'll see what works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's all there, you're just not using the Function **as** a function. You need to store the result in something, like 'NewArray'..?

```
Public col As New Collection
Public Sub Test()
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "Template") <> 0 Then
        col.Add ws.Name
    End If
Next ws


' Tweaked as per Vityata's comment

If col.Count > 0 Then 
    newarray = collectionToArray(col)
Else
    ' Do something else
End If

End Sub

Function collectionToArray(c As Collection) As Variant()
    Dim a() As Variant: ReDim a(0 To c.Count - 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        a(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next
    collectionToArray = a
End Function
```

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> collectionToArray (col)
> ```

Notice that whitespace between the function's name and its argument list? That's the VBE telling you this:

*I'll take that argument, **evaluate it as a value**, then pass it `ByVal` to that procedure you're calling, even if the signature for that procedure says `ByRef`, explicitly or not.*

This "extraneous parentheses" habit is inevitably going to make you bump into weird "Object Required" runtime errors at one point or another: lose it.

The `Function` is overdoing it IMO: a `Variant` can perfectly well wrap an array, so I'd change its signature to return a `Variant` instead of a `Variant()`.

`Integer` being a 16-bit signed integer type (i.e. `short` in some other languages), it's probably a better idea to use a `Long` instead (32-bit signed integer, i.e. `int` in some other languages) - that way you'll avoid running into "Overflow" issues when you need to deal with more than 32,767 values (especially common if a worksheet is involved).

> ```
> Public col As New Collection
> ```

This makes `col` an *auto-instantiated object variable*, and it has potentially surprising side-effects. Consider this code:

```
Dim c As New Collection
c.Add 42
Set c = Nothing
c.Add 42
Debug.Print c.Count
```

What do you expect this code to do? If you thought "error 91, because the object reference is `Nothing`", you've been bitten by auto-instantiation. Best avoid it, and keep declaration and assignments as separate instructions.

Other than that, [CLR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153675/1188513) has your solution: a `Function` should *return* a value, that the calling code should consume.

```
result = MyFunction(args)
```

You'll notice the VBE clearing any whitespace you might be tempted to add between `MyFunction` and `(args)` here: that's the VBE telling you this:

*I'll take that argument, pass it to `MyFunction`, and assign the function's return value to `result`.*

Comment: That is actually a pretty good answer, I had to read it twice and to play a bit with code to get exactly what do you mean in the first part. Probabaly you may consider adding an example like this one - https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/ByReferenceByValue.vb to make the first part more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

This is my [collectionToArray](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/OOP/DictionaryAndArray/CollectionToArray.vb) function:

```
Public Function CollectionToArray(myCol As Collection) As Variant

    Dim result  As Variant
    Dim cnt     As Long
    
    If myCol.Count = 0 Then
        CollectionToArray = Array()
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ReDim result(myCol.Count - 1)
    For cnt = 0 To myCol.Count - 1
        result(cnt) = myCol(cnt + 1)
    Next cnt
    CollectionToArray = result

End Function
```

It is better than the one you are using, because it will not give an error, if the collection is empty.
To avoid the error on an empty collection in your case, you may consider adding a check like this:

```
If col.Count > 0 Then k = CollectionToArray(col)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just used this code, but the redim should be myCol.count-1. Otherwise you get an empty member in the array which can cause problems (in my case in a RemoveDuplicates).

Comment: I do not see the reason for the redim `myCol.Count-1` This is what I got with the normal code, without `-1` - https://ibb.co/iQfJ38 No empty members...

Comment: The argument in the redim is the upper boundary

Comment: The line should be ReDim result(myCol.Count - 1) because otherwise the array has an empty element at the end...

Comment: @Grim - actually there was some kind of a strange case, that was urging me not to do it that way, but I cannot remember it exactly. Checking the screenshot from my previous comment now, I see it was working ok. Just wondering when it should go wrong... Anyway I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a standard collection, you can use a dictionary because of the .keys method that can transfer all info to an array. Less coding, simple :)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr

Dim Dic As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Dic = New Dictionary

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.Name Like "*Template*" Then

Dic.Add ws.Name, "Awesome"

End If

Next ws

arr = Dic.Keys