# Where is the error in this simple macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Sub ADD_PEDIDO_AtualizaPagamentos()

If M6 = erro Then
MsgBox ("Erro!")

Else
Sheets("ADD_PEDIDO").[M9].Value = "Done!"

End If
End Sub
```

Without the "IF" the code works fine. But after I insert IF and Else, I always receive the Error code.
And as you can see in the above code, the M6 cell giver the "OK" to insert, but macro gives me error.

Any help?

[image: Without Activate Macro][image: After Activate Macro]

Comment: "_I always receive the Error code_"... Care to share this error? Also, you would get better results posting your code instead of making it an image.

Comment: I've edited the post so the code appears, hopefully it'll be shown soon.

Comment: No problem with code. I just want to fix that ;)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks, my bad. Glad my edit is okay, but I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some severe syntax issues in your coding.

You should refer to a range using the ***worksheet*.Range** method.

```
Sub ADD_PEDIDO_AtualizaPagamentos()
    If Worksheets("ADD_PEDIDO").Range("M6") = "erro" Then
        MsgBox "Erro!"
    Else
        Worksheets("ADD_PEDIDO").Range("M9").Value = "Done!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Notice that space between `MsgBox` and `("Erro!")`? That's the VBE telling you something's off. Remove these extraneous parentheses and drop the habit of putting parens everywhere - you'll soon run into compile errors otherwise. Also prefer the `Worksheets` collection over `Sheets`, and ideally qualify it with a `Workbook` instance - here the unqualified `Range` and `Sheets` calls both respectively implicitly refer to the active worksheet and active workbook, which *will* cause problems in the future too.

Comment: See the top part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153905/1188513) for more detailed information about the parentheses issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak Spanish so I don't know if erro is a key term in VBA in another language, but if you're checking for the actual string erro, you should change your if statement line to. Also surround M6 with Range("") so that it knows you aren't referring to a variable called M6.

```
If Range("M6") = "erro" Then
```

Comment: AFAIK, VBA is always in English.  Or, strictly speaking, in American. (I wish they would learn how to spell "colour"!!)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was only written in English! Have to disagree on "color" though, it's all about minimizing keystrokes ;-)

Comment: @YowE3K that colorful behavior is entirely by design =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug +u+u !

Answer (score 2):

UNTESTED:

try replacing:

```
If M6 = erro Then
```

with:

```
If Range("M6").Text = "erro" Then
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you should first learn how to refer to a particular cell or range of cells in VBA by reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-cells-and-ranges-by-using-a1-notation) up — then I think you should be able to answer your own question.
2. Without the if...then in your line 2, it becomes an initialization (assignment) of an hitherto undeclared variable M6, just like `x = ...’.

   3. It may be a good practice for you to add `Option Explicit` to every module of vba codes you write; then VBA would be more generous in telling you what went wrong.

Comment: This feels more like a series of comments than a definite answer.