# Output array to excel with VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

Im am trying to output an array coming from JsonConverter  to excel but I get an error 1004:

```
Sub test()
    Dim parsed As Object
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456}}")
    Set myArray = parsed("b")
    Set TxtRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project").Range("A44:D44")
    TxtRng.Value = Application.Transpose(myArray)
End Sub
```

The error is at `TxtRng.Value = Application.Transpose(myArray)`.

Can someone help solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You shouldn't assume that it is commonly known what `JsonConverter` because it is not a build-in object. I assume you are talking about https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON ?

In your example, `parsed` will return a `Dictionary` and `parsed("b")` will return a `Collection`. `Application.Transpose` expects a (2-dimensional) array as parameter, but will not work with a collection.

Probably the easiest way to solve this is simply to loop over the collection. Or use a helper function like similar to [Converting VBA Collection to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153398/converting-vba-collection-to-array) to create an intermediate array first